# What happened to read error rate on my 7 month old WD HDD? Is this a concern?

Tags: hard-drive, smart

I have a WD Black 7200RPM Laptop HDD and it is the secondary drive. I bought it like 7 months ago. And I don’t use it much for any heavy work. Just saving some files and that’s it.

I took a screenshot from `CrystalDiskInfo` about 3 months ago and I kept it and today I just opened `CrystalDiskInfo` and compared the values with that old screenshot and I see the `Read Error Rate` value has changed.

```
Attribute Name    | Current | Worst | Threshold
Read Error Rate   |    100  |   253 |    51
```

But today it is,

```
Attribute Name    | Current | Worst | Threshold
Read Error Rate   |    200  |   200 |    51
```

Why have the current and worst values changed? What happened to HDD. Is this bad?

And also `Start/Stop Count`, `Load/Unload Cycle Count` values are also changed.

Previously they were,

```
Attribute Name          | Current | Worst | Threshold
Start/Stop Count        |    100  |   100 |     0
Load/Unload Cycle Count |    200  |   200 |     0
```

But now they are,

```
Attribute Name          | Current | Worst | Threshold
Start/Stop Count        |    98   |   98  |     0
Load/Unload Cycle Count |    199  |   199 |     0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Normalized value", commonly referred to as just "value",
is a most universal measurement, on the scale from 0 (bad) to some maximum
(good) value.

Maximum values are typically 100, 200 or 253.
Rule of thumb is: High values are good, low values are bad.

In your case, the values of `100` and `200` only meant that there was
yet no meaningful data, as the disk was new.

After 7 months, some of the values have changed and now have meaning
beyond the meaningless "100" or "200".

You should be happy to see that "Read Error Rate" is still unset,
meaning that your disk had no errors and is in good shape.

See
[ZAR - Quick guide to understanding S.M.A.R.T. information](https://www.z-a-recovery.com/manual/smart.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So what about `Start/Stop Count` and `Load/Unload Cycle Count`?

Comment: See [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/735061/s-m-a-r-t-whats-the-difference-between-start-stop-cycle-count-and-load-unl). These are usually real values, not normalized ones, but some of them have an internal structure of bit-fields and need interpretation (which many SMART utilities do for us).

Comment: So you mean my HDD is in good health?

Comment: The disk is in perfect health and didn't have a single error during all the months that you used it.

Comment: Oh that relieves me. Thank you very much for the answer. Once the bounty is available I will reward you.

Answer (score 1):

"T.E.C." (Threshold Exceeded Condition) is the alert condition when any parameter falls below threshold.

**All the thresholds use inverse logic.** i.e. going <= threshold is a failure.  But RAW data is cumulative but inverted into something and rounded off as ratio.

So error rate is counting (Terra or Penta) bytes transferred (rounded exponents) between burst errors before ECC hardware error correction code (ECC) is invoked.

So the threshold triggers are inverted to what (You & I) thought they meant.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.